# What is the difference between 'all business requirements' and 'all the business requirements'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, articles

How do we separate the following sentences in terms of meaning?

> We cater to ***all*** business requirements.
>
> We cater to ***all the*** business requirements.

IMO, 'all business' denotes each and every business while 'all the business' denotes all the activities of the business. Am I right? Please give better sentences in this context if any.

Comment: Do you mean "We cater *to* all business requirements" meaning requirements that a company needs. "We cater all business requirements" means you will serve food (catering).

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I mean 'cater to all business requirements'. Edited.

Comment: @Peter: I think that's misleading. If a company's website said *We cater all business requirements* I still wouldn't think it likely they were in the "commercial catering" business. The only thing I'd be sure of would be that their marketing department was staffed by non-native speakers.

Answer (score 2):

(In this context and many other contexts), `the` implies something already being discussed, or something that has already been specified.

---

If you have been talking about business requirements and want to refer specifically to those requirements that you have already talked about (not to other requirements that you have not talked about),

`all the business requirements` is appropriate.

(This one seems less common to me. It would often be clarified:

`all the business requirements that we have discussed`)

---

If you want to talk about business requirements including ones that have not been discussed,

`all business requirements` is appropriate.

(This one seems better for your example.)

Comment: Good point. There may also be an unintended 'exclusionary' aspect to using *the business* - e.g. cater to all the *business* requirements (only), but perhaps not the *staff health and safety* requirements. This is arguably implicit in the *all business* version, but seems to be more prominent in the *all the business* version.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence

> We cater to all business requirements.

is a general statement referring to every need a business may have.

Your second sentence

> We cater to all *the* business requirements.

is either referring to requirements which have been discussed in a separate context, or the sentence is unfinished

> We cater to all *the* business requirements *you may have*.
>   We cater to all *the necessary* business requirements.

Usually, this sentence might be phrased

> We cater to all *your* business requirements.